# How to pass data from one view to controller in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#

I am redirecting from one view to another by `windows.location` and I used the syntax like that:

```
windows.location.href = "/controller/action?var" + val;
```

What should I do to pass more than one values?

Comment: simply concatenate as you are doing first one

Comment: `"/controller/action?var=" + val + "&var2=" + var2`

Comment: `windows.location` should be `window.location`. I didn't change it in case it's an error in your code

Comment: Satpal gives correct comment, and values should be "safe" (url-encoded)

Comment: Notation of arguments without `'?'` (goal: be google friendly), some www engines realise (without too much support in standards)  has hign positioned "slash" form `/controller/action/var/" + val + "/var2/" + var2 - BUT ITS NOT SURE,  i don't know aspx can realise such syntax  (edit: Bendan write is asnwer that realize)

Comment: Thank you Satpal and all others.